Amount Transfer Between Different Accounts
I implemented the below classes for transfer amount between different accounts. Used ConcurrentHashMap and Stamped Lock to handle concurrency.
Am I missing any important concepts here? Are there any improvements that can be done to improve performance and key builder logic? What could be some few followup questions/additional implementations that can be asked after implementing this in a live coding interview?
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock;

public class BankAccount {

private static final Map<Long, BankAccount> accountMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private BigDecimal balance;
private Long accountNumber;
private AccountType accountType;
private AccountStatus status;
private final StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();

BankAccount(Long accountNumber, AccountType accountType) {
    balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(0L);
    setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    this.accountType = accountType != null ? accountType : AccountType.SAVINGS;
    this.status = AccountStatus.ACTIVE;
    accountMap.putIfAbsent(accountNumber, this);
}

public void setAccountNumber(Long accountNumber) {
    if (accountNumber == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Account Number");
    }
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public static Map<Long, BankAccount> getAccountMap() {
    return accountMap;
}

public StampedLock getLock() {
    return lock;
}

public BigDecimal getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public AccountStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(AccountStatus accountStatus) {
    this.status = accountStatus;
}

public AccountType getAccountType() {
    return accountType;
}

public void setAccountType(AccountType accountType) {
    this.accountType = accountType;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    return o instanceof BankAccount other && Objects.equals(accountNumber, other.accountNumber)
            && Objects.equals(accountType, other.accountType);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.accountNumber, this.accountType);
}


}


  import java.math.BigDecimal;

  public interface IAccountService {

  BankAccount findAccountByAccountNumber(Long accountNumber);

  boolean transfer(BigDecimal amount, Long fromAccountNumber, Long toAccountNumber);

  void validateAmount(BigDecimal amount);

  void validateStatus(BankAccount bankAccount);

 }
 

import com.java.learning.bankaccount.exception.BankAccountGeneralException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock;

@Resource
public class AccountService implements IAccountService {

@Override
public BankAccount findAccountByAccountNumber(Long accountNumber) {
    if (accountNumber == null) {
        throw new BankAccountGeneralException("Illegal Account Number");
    }
    return Optional.of(BankAccount.getAccountMap().get(accountNumber))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BankAccountGeneralException("Bank Account Not 
     Found"));
 }

@Override
public boolean transfer(BigDecimal amount, Long fromAccountNumber, Long 
                        toAccountNumber) {

    if (fromAccountNumber != null && fromAccountNumber.equals(toAccountNumber)) {
        throw new BankAccountGeneralException("Self Transfer Not Allowed");
    }

    BankAccount fromAccount = findAccountByAccountNumber(fromAccountNumber);
    BankAccount toAccount = findAccountByAccountNumber(toAccountNumber);
    validateAmount(amount);
    StampedLock toAccountLock = toAccount.getLock();
    StampedLock fromAccountLock = fromAccount.getLock();
    long toAccountStamp = toAccountLock.tryWriteLock();
    long fromAccountStamp = fromAccountLock.tryWriteLock();

    try {

        if (toAccountLock.validate(toAccountStamp) && 
            fromAccountLock.validate(fromAccountStamp)) {

            toAccountStamp = toAccountLock.writeLock();
            fromAccountStamp = fromAccountLock.writeLock();
            validateStatus(fromAccount);
            validateStatus(toAccount);
            validateFromAccountBalance(fromAccount.getBalance(), amount);
            toAccount.setBalance(toAccount.getBalance().add(amount));
            fromAccount.setBalance(fromAccount.getBalance().subtract(amount));
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        toAccountLock.unlockWrite(toAccountStamp);
        fromAccountLock.unlockWrite(fromAccountStamp);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void validateAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    if (amount == null || amount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
        throw new BankAccountGeneralException("Invalid Transaction Amount");
    }
}

@Override
public void validateStatus(BankAccount bankAccount) {
    if (bankAccount.getStatus() != AccountStatus.ACTIVE) {
        throw new BankAccountGeneralException("Account Not Active");
    }
}

private void validateFromAccountBalance(BigDecimal balance, BigDecimal amount) {
    if (balance.compareTo(amount) < 0) {
        throw new BankAccountGeneralException("Insufficient Account Balance");
    }
  }
}

 public enum AccountStatus {
  ACTIVE, CLOSED;
 }


public enum AccountType {
 SAVINGS, CURRENT;
}

  public class BankAccountGeneralException extends RuntimeException {

   public BankAccountGeneralException(String errorMessage) {
      super(errorMessage);
   }

  }



Overall Design

Validation inside a Service

Validating if transaction amount is not null and not negative, as well as checking if accounts exist, should take place at the system boundary. I.e. when the data enters your application, not in your business logic.
Validate DTOs, don't propagate invalid data to services.
The only checks that should take place inside a service: if the balance is sufficient and if both accounts are active.
Also worth to mention, that in order to perform validation without enduring the pain of performing every value manually you can make use Jakarta Bean Validation, which is a simple annotation-based tool.

Why BankAccount holds a map of bank accounts?

Don't see any reason why this map should be included into BankAccount class. Additionally, using a static mutable state is a dirty hack that should be avoided.
It's definitely not a responsibility of this class. You need to introduce an abstraction concerned with retrieving accounts (basically a simple fake repository), that where this map belongs.

Getter & Setters vs Proper behavior

Object-orientation is about exposing behavior, not data.
There are getters and setter all over the place in the BankAccount, no domain-specific methods. That's what is called an anemic domain model.
Implementation

findAccountByAccountNumber()

Essentially, it's "find account by ID" (and it will be more concise if you name it like this).
There are couple fishy things about this method (take time and try to spot them):
@Override
public BankAccount findAccountByAccountNumber(Long accountNumber) {
    if (accountNumber == null) {
        throw new BankAccountGeneralException("Illegal Account Number");
    }
    return Optional.of(BankAccount.getAccountMap().get(accountNumber))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new BankAccountGeneralException("Bank Account Not Found"));
}


BankAccountGeneralException("Bank Account Not Found") will never be thrown due to a bug in this piece of code.

If an account with the given ID doesn't exist and get() returns null, method Optional.of() will throw a NullPointerException (see documentation).

Secondly, this piece of code is not very clean, and it's not a proper to use Optional class.


The primary use of Optional is as follows: Optional is intended to
provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where
there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null
for that is overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.
A typical code smell is, instead of the code using method chaining to
handle an Optional returned from some method, it creates an Optional
from something that's nullable, in order to chain methods and avoid
conditionals.

Quotes from the answer by @StuartMarks, Java and OpenJDK developer
So don't trust blindly if some Good Samaritan will advise changing it to Optional.ofNullable(), because that's not how this type is intended to be used in the first place.

transfer()

You have the same bug with locking as is one of the question before, namely releasing the locks that might not have been acquired:
try {
    if (toAccountLock.validate(toAccountStamp) &&
        fromAccountLock.validate(fromAccountStamp)) {
                
        // critical section
    }
} finally {
    toAccountLock.unlockWrite(toAccountStamp);
    fromAccountLock.unlockWrite(fromAccountStamp);
}

Instead, it should be:
if (toAccountLock.validate(toAccountStamp) &&
    fromAccountLock.validate(fromAccountStamp)) {

    try {
        // critical section
    } finally {
    toAccountLock.unlockWrite(toAccountStamp);
    fromAccountLock.unlockWrite(fromAccountStamp);
}

Apart from that, this method bears a lot of accidental complexity that stems from the design issues described above.
Also, I'm not sure about your decision to perform transaction without blocking, and return false if locks are not immediately available. Are you going to ask the user to retry, in this such a case? Then what if the subsequent attempt of non-blocking lock acquisition will fail? It might result in more requests to process.
Imaging you want to purchase something from a shop which doing great, their accounts receive lots of payments from customers, so you happen to be unlucky and repeatedly stumble on an ongoing transaction each time. And your bank repeatedly respond "sorry, try again later". Doesn't sound very nice.
Consider acquiring locks with the specified timeout instead.

BankAccount.getBalance()

This method reads the balance value without locking.
Although, the only place this it's invoked in the method transfer() after acquiring a write lock, which guarantees exclusive access to the thread holding the lock and the value safe to read; it's still an issue.
You might introduce a bug, if you decide to use getBalance() as is without locking elsewhere. The same applies to getStatus().
Recommendations

Start with fixing the bugs.
Move the basic validation into the controller, that will remove some noise.
Use your domain type in parameter types of the transfer() method instead of Long IDs.
Move the accountMap out of the BankAccount.
And instead of treating BankAccount as a bag of values manipulated manually, consider introducing proper behavior into this domain type. For instance, every account should allow withdrawing and depositing money. Implement these methods in BankAccount (not in the service), with proper locking. And then, think of how you can refactor transfer().
If you will attempt to address the previous bullet point, beware that StamptLock is not reentrant. I.e. if, let's say, a thread that has acquired a write lock on a StampedLock calls a method that attempts to acquire either a read or write lock on the same StampedLock, it will block itself.


Object-orientation is about exposing behavior, not data.  =>  You have mastered THE FORCE.

@Alexander Thanks for the review.All four points looks good. Do you have any improvement recommendation regarding thread safety and concurrency here  or any good follow up questions ?

@Alexander Why Validation is done inside a Service? --> whenever any transfer is initiated, are we supposed not to validate the amount and the current account status ?

@Jill You should validate if amount is not null and not negative, and if accounts with the given IDs exist in the controller. If something is wrong, don't proceed with calling the service (updated the answer).

Absolutely Right.But for a 45 minute round, i thought I can skip writing controller or a separate validator framework(Example Spring Bean Validator). So added the logic as part of same service class. The bug regarding lock that you identified is an amazing work , its just one try above but makes a lot of difference.Just Wow.Thanks a lot.

@Jill Understandable. But application components are not floating in a vacuum, in order to design a solution that is clean maintainable we should properly delineate their responsibilities (writing clean code is one of the topic this site is focus on). Regarding Java Bean Validation, it's not a tricky beast to subdue, in this case you're good with standard annotations on DTO fields @NotNull, @DecimalMin("0.01")  (usually we charge at least one monetary unit).

introduce behavior for locking/unlocking instead of getting hands on locks and manipulating with them manually. ==> Sorry, I could not understand this part of your answer ,you mean synchronized method instead of a lock  ?

@Jill No, I didn't mean that. You don't need to draw the private lock instance out from an account, in order to lock the account. Try to avoid treating your domain entities like bags of values with getters and setters, which basically ruins the encapsulation. Expose the behavior instead of exposing their internals. Try to introduce withdraw(), deposit(), isActive() in BankAccount. Then try to refactor transfer() in the service, method acquiring and releasing write lock on the BankAccount will be useful. Also mind that StampedLock is not reentrant.
